# How to create 45 imageviews without lots of duplicate code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uiimageview

I need to create 45 50x50 pixel images on my form. Here are the first 8. I plan on loading images into them later. Is there a better way to do this with a loop? The code below works fine when I load an image in. I just wondered if there was a better way to create all 45.

```
UIView * wview1;
UIView * wview2;
UIView * wview3;
UIView * wview4;
UIView * wview5;
UIView * wview6;
UIView * wview7;
UIView * wview8;    
wview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 50)];
wview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 20, 50, 50)];
wview3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 20, 50, 50)];
wview4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 20, 50, 50)];
wview5 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 20, 50, 50)];
wview6 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(340, 20, 50, 50)];
wview7 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(410, 20, 50, 50)];
wview8 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(480, 20, 50, 50)];
wview1.tag = 1;
wview2.tag = 2;
wview3.tag = 3;
wview4.tag = 4;
wview5.tag = 5;
wview6.tag = 6;
wview7.tag = 7;
wview8.tag = 8;
[self.view addSubview:wview1];
[self.view addSubview:wview2];
[self.view addSubview:wview3];
[self.view addSubview:wview4];
[self.view addSubview:wview5];
[self.view addSubview:wview6];
[self.view addSubview:wview7];
[self.view addSubview:wview8];
```

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with some basic concepts in programming, such as loops...

Comment: @Undo's answer is correct but I would recommend some reading about loops in general: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely!

```
for (int i=0; i++; i<45)
{
    UIView *wview;   
    wview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10 + 60*i, 20, 50, 50)];
    wview.tag = i+1;
    [self.view addSubview:wview];
}
```

Should do the job.